# Why does an object of type Integer turn to a primitive type?

Tags: java, types, integer, int

So I have this code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int i = 3;
    int j = new Integer(5);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Boolean.toString(j.equals(5)));
}
```

It should open a message dialog with the text "true". The problem is it gives a compiler error saying that I can't invoke a method on the primitive type int. Why is this happening?

Casting `((Integer) j).equals(5)` works as expected. I just don't understand why the object `j` is turning into a primitive type.

Comment: Because you are explicitly stating that `j` should be used as an `int` and not as an `integer`?

Comment: because you *declared* `j` to be an `int`, not an `Integer`.

Comment: You declared `int j`, not `Integer j`.

Answer (score 3):

> I just don't understand why the object j is turning into a primitive type.

Because `j` is not an object in the first place. It is a primitive `int`. Your `new Integer(5)` is automatically unboxed on assignment.